# Class will not remove using classList.remove()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add 'open' class to `<div className='menu' onClick={handleSidebar}>` when I click it, and remove when clicked again. In devtools I can see 'open' be added but when I click it again it will not remove. Is there a different approach to removing class?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './menu.styles.scss';

function Menu({ handleSidebar }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    let menuOpen = false;
    menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (!menuOpen) {
        menu.classList.add('open');
        menuOpen = !menuOpen;
      } else {
        menu.classList.remove('open');
        menuOpen = !menuOpen;
      }
    });
  });
  return (
    <div className='menu' onClick={handleSidebar}>
      <div className='menu-btn'></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: put `let menuOpen = false;` outside `useEffect`

Comment: You should checkout [`classnames`](https://jedwatson.github.io/classnames/) package available via `npm`

Comment: What you are trying to do is not Reactic. you should use state to reflect changes in the DOM. Please bother to read the docs

Comment: I can't say with full certainty, but I would imagine any manual changes to the DOM like that would just be overwritten on the next render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off doing this with `useState`...the way you have it now with the `document.querySelector` is sort of besides the point of react.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './menu.styles.scss';

function Menu({ handleSidebar }) {

  const [ open, setOpen ] = useState(true)

  return (

    <div className={`menu ${open ? 'open' : ''}`} onClick={setOpen(!open)}>
      <div className='menu-btn'></div>
    </div>

  )

}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. Also, since I am bring in another function from a parent component 'handleSidebar'. Am I able to have multiple onClick events? For example, `<div
      className={`menu ${open ? 'open' : ''}`}
      onClick={() => {
        handleSidebar();
        setOpen(!open);
      }}
    >` I was confused because if I do handleSidebar instead of handleSidebar(), it gives me an error. I though handleSidebar() wasnt ideal because it runs the function every time component renders instead of just when clicked?

Comment: yes technically you could do that with the way you wrote it.  its a little messy though.  might be better to define another function within your component, like `myOnClickFunction = () =>  { handleSidebar(); setOpen(!open) }`, and then within your `return`'s `onClick`, do a `onClick={myOnClickFunction }`.  That's just a stylistic choice though, what you wrote should work just fine.

Comment: Also, if my answer helped you, it is customary to mark it as the answer by hitting the check mark. This helps me get meaningless internet points, which everyone loves.

Comment: Perfect, I appreciate it. I did hit the check mark, should be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not reach else part as u assign false to menuOpen. So the if condition will satisfy evey time.